# .NET Service Hosting

Tags: .net, service, hosting

Is there any online service that hosts .NET code and runs it for me? I am not looking for a web server, in fact, I am more interested in running services with no UI and I am okay with them not being accessible from the Internet, all I need is for them to be able to run non stop (or to be scheduled to happen frequently and often) and to access the Internet themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use Microsoft Azure - its not free, but you can schedule your access to it, ramp up and down according to your needs.

Comment: I have to admit I have no experience with Auze. I thought it's only web hosting too, am I not correct in this? Could Azure be used for something similar to what I described in a comment on @windowshostingasp.net's answer?

Comment: Ok, if you are not writing an IIS hosted application, then you could hire an Azure VM. An Extra-Small VM is priced at £9 per month (according to http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/)

Comment: I've signed up for Azure Subscription and now I am able to run my application 24/7 and make it send me e-mail based on it's input that it gathers from the Internet. I love it, thanks for your answer.